# add other link when on device or desktop

Tags: html, email, responsive-design

I have to make an email. 
When you open the email on a device all the links has to refer to the m.website.be, but on a desktop it has to refer to the website.be

Is there a way to do this, and that works in every mailclient ?

thanks in advance

Comment: tbh, the issue is really the fact that its not redirecting to the mobile version of the site, but ill answer anyway

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make it, some email clients even don't understand HTML.

The only way I know is to make it on a server side when your client tries to open the website.

When he comes from the desktop - redirect to the desktop.
When mobile - redirect to mobile.

Everything is easy.

Answer (score 1):

If doing a redirect on the actual site itself is not a possibility then the only way I can think of is by applying [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and hiding the  m.website.com link for desktop and hiding the non m.website.com link for mobiles. You may run into issues here where some clients dont pick up on the media query.

Answer (score 1):

If you really really really wanted to do the trick, you could do something like this with mime/multipart messages and alternative contents (i.e. writing the content to each alternative with different URL). However, even in that case you should be able to control which alternative the receivers email client opens. Some mobile clients might always open text/plain.

Since the solution will not fully meet your needs, I will not go into details. If you want to know more, read the rfc:s related to mime/multipart email content.

I recommend you leave it to your reader by writing the email like this:
"If in mobile device open m.website.be, on a desktop, please use website.be." or even better, use the server side redirect that most websites do anyway.